# Discord.js Bot Quiz Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, replit

I was looking for a command that would give a question and 4 options ( if possible as buttons or reactions), where i could give questions in the code with the correct answer, but all i could find online were for slash commands, getting questions from a website or were v12 of discord.js.

I don't know much, so any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout my library **discord-trivia**, used for integrating full trivia matches.

```
npm i discord-trivia
```

You can use either Messages or slash command interactions

```js
// Namespace
const { TriviaManager } = require('discord-trivia');
const trivia = new TriviaManager();

// Function
const game = trivia.createGame(message); // or createGame(interaction)

game
   .start()
   .catch(console.error);
```

Check out the [NPM page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-trivia) for a full walkthrough on customization

Comment: Thanks! This works great! But is there any way to add our own questions? Is it also possible to change the start and end embeds?

Comment: The questions come from the [Open Trivia Database API](https://opentdb.com/), You can propose questions there. Currently the only aspect about an embed you can edit is it's color via `TriviaManagerOptions#theme`. I'll take these questions as feature requests for the future 